# loading translate dynamic using @ngx-translate/core

Tags: node.js, angular5, translate

loading translate dynamically using @ngx-translate/core but not get even if translate not set to specific key they not show default value({{'Language' | translate}}) mean if 'Language' key not set they show 'Language' in website but they not show.Please help me